# Highcharts Gantt - Dynamic grid cell height

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-gantt

Is there a way to dynamically increase the height of each row as shown in the image below:

[image: Sample]

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the rows with the `yAxis.staticScale` property.

```js
yAxis: {
    staticScale: 100
},
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gsc4d5r7/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/yAxis.staticScale

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, its working, but i need to change the height of each row. Some of the rows have small labels, while others have very large labels. Please help.

Comment: There is a ticket on the library's GitHub repository related to this. You can also find a workaround there: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15171

Comment: Please help me to find out how to calculate breaks, breaksize, from and to points?
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/my36or2u/